# How to add a small straight line (I mean like this: a̅ b̅ X̅) onto a character inside a string?

Tags: swift

I want to add small straight line onto some desired characters/numbers inside a string inside textview. I couldn't find a solution. Maybe using NSMutableAttributedString. Meanwhile, I mean doing this programmatically. There is strikethrough style, but not overstrike style. Or maybe adding the letters "a" and "_" with different .baseline values. But how to add both characters onto each other then?
Is it possible?

EDIT: Due to make a try for the helpful answers below, I think to make the line at a spesific height is needed. "A\u{0305}" makes the up line very close to the character, as if it sticks. Is there a way to make it at specific height? For example, if we assume that all the keyboard-inputted characters are written inside every single boxes, the ceiling side of these boxes could be lined?

Comment: What showed up in your post is a lower-case A with a tilde on top, (US term for it, or a virgulilla in Spanish) and a curved accent on the bottom. Your question asks how to add a small straight line to a character, but since we can't see that, it isn't clear what you are asking for. Does your small straight line go at the bottom of your character? Through the middle?

Comment: Do you mean like `a̅ b̅ X̅` where the overline is directly above each glyph? Or a line at some fixed height based on the font, such as the cap-height? For glyphs above that height, do you want the line to cut through them?

Comment: @DuncanC Since I couldn't find by googling an example, I couldn't write it, just expressed by words. Now, I see Rob has written, a̅ b̅ X̅, therefore I am editing the post now.

Comment: @RobNapier Yes I mean exactly like what you have written. I mean to any individual characters, like numbers also. Not at a specific height, like the chars you have written, just above the glyphs.

Comment: I did exactly what Duncan's answer explains. (That's an COMBINING OVERLINE.) What you seem to want will require hand-drawing the line. While you can integrate it with NSAttributedString to pass the data if you like, you'll need to draw the yourself with Core Graphics after using Core Text to work out the location. It's definitely doable, but it's not trivial, and depends a bit on how much other flexibility you need (are these long strings that need to wrap in a text view, or single-line strings? Is there other formatting like bolding, or multiple fonts? How does it interact with diacritics?)

Comment: Also it'll matter a little whether this is UIKit or AppKit (SwiftUI would need to embed one of those; SwiftUI can't do this directly). Anyone experienced in Cocoa text layout should be able to implement a basic form of this (find the glyph bounding boxes to get the start and end *x*, and and use the line fragment box to get the *y*), but I unfortunately don't have time to develop a full answer right now. (If you get in a bind, and no one can answer quickly, I can take it as a small contract, but I'm betting someone can answer. There are other CoreText devs here.)

Answer (score 4):

So this (*note: see edit below*) appears to be an "a tilde ogonek" (it's Lithuanian).

You can write it for instance as follows using these two Unicode characters:

```
let atildeogonek = "\u{0105}\u{0303}"
let title = "How to add a small straight line (I mean like this: \(atildeogonek)) onto a character inside a string?"
```

The first character is the a with an ogonek, the second one is the tilde.

**EDIT**: The initial question specifically asked about the character `ą̃` ("a tilde ogonek") in the title, and I used this code to demonstrate how to use Unicode characters in a Swift string. After posting this answer, the question was edited to be more general about "a line above a character".

Comment: So doing every characters and numbers like this: a̅ b̅ X̅ is only possible as your method?

Comment: @AnthonSanthez I'm sure it can also be done by drawing a line for instance in a `CALayer` on top of your string. But that would cause a lot of headaches trying to keep them in sync and probably requires using `TextKit` as well. So if these are actual characters, then yes, use this method.

Comment: This answer generates the glyph the OP showed in their title, "ą̃". It sounds like they actually want characters like a̅ b̅ X̅, which is different.

Comment: Agreed - that additional info was added after I posted my answer. But OP can use the same approach with the corresponding Unicode values. If that's what they want.

Answer (score 3):

Programmatically, you could use a function like this:

```
func overline(character: Character) -> Character? {
    return "\(character)\u{0305}".first
}
```

That will take a character as input and return a new character (glyph) that has had the Unicode combining overline character added to it. It will return nil if adding the combining overline character fails.

The code `print(overline(character:"A")!)`, for example, returns "A̅"

Or, if you want to add an overline to every character in a string, you could use a function like this:

```
func overline(characters: String) -> [Character?] {
    return  Array(characters).map { return "\($0)\u{0305}".first
    }
}
```

(I'm not sure if there are any characters for which the above will fail, so I'm not sure if force-unwrapping the result is safe. Thus I left the result of both functions to be optional `Character`/Array of `Character`.)

Comment: thank you. I tried this but it makes the up line very close to the character, as if it sticks. Is there a way to make it at specific height? For example, if we assume that all the keyboard-inputted characters are written inside every single boxes, the ceiling side of these boxes can be lined?

Comment: @AnthonSanthez - then maybe you need to look at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1524729-boundingrect and similar methods.

Comment: the documentation looks quite general and complex:(

Comment: Yes, it is very complex, hence using Unicode is so much easier. But, you haven't clearly explained if you are looking at existing characters (such as ą̃, or X̅) , or if you really want to just draw a line drawn above any character. Maybe you can add a picture of the desired end result?

Comment: I would strongly advise against trying to render custom drawing of lines above characters. There is a defined way to modify a glyph in Unicode with an overline. Use that. You would have to write hundreds and hundreds of lines of very fussy, fragile font parsing and CGGraphics code to draw custom lines over your characters and maintain them in the right place.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily find the unicodes of ā or ą̃ by using the xcode's own **Character Viewer**. Just follow the following steps :

hit : **Control** + **Command** + **SpaceBar**

If you get a compact one like this, click the upper right corner icon to expand it.

[image]

When expanded, Click the settings gear in the corner . Select customize list.

[image]

select **Enclosed Characters**

[image]

Go down to the bottom and open Code tables then add **Unicode**.

[image]

Now, just search for your required **Character** and you can check its unicode value. here i am searching **ā**

[image]

to print unicode's value :

```
print("\u{0101}")
```

Comment: thank you for such a comprehensive reply. But I meant doing that programmatically. Sorry that I haven't been clear about the question. I edited it now. Thanks for your effort